# Why c++ no more shows index out of range on giving index for accessing character of a string, which is more than the length of string?

Tags: c++

[Think C++ Allen B. Downey, chapter 7, section 7.6 A run-time error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7Irw.png)

After reading the excerpt about run time error and index out of range error in c++. I tried to execute the same in my compiler of c++ which is running in vs code. But even on trying positive out of range index as well as negative index. I wasn't getting any error instead getting an unexpected (erronous) character being printed on the console. The code I was trying to run is:

```
int main();
{
string user_input = "hello";
char a = user_input[100];
cout << a << endl;
return 0;
}
```

positive index out of range was giving new line as the output. While negative index out of range (like -100) was each time giving different character on the console. Please explain the correct behaviour of c++ and why current c++ is not working as written in book? Is the book incorrect or it is recent version thing.

Comment: `user_input[100]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Try `user_input.at(100)` for fun.

Comment: @AnoopRana some compilers will check the bounds for access if you're compiling in a debug mode.  But it's not required by the standard so you can't rely on it.

Comment: The information shown in the image is simply wrong assuming there isn't some missing context for e.g. a specific compiler configuration with bounds checking enabled. There is no guarantee that indexing out-of-bounds with `[]` in C++ causes a runtime error. It causes undefined behavior, meaning that there is no guarantee at all of what will happen.

Comment: Commonly debug builds will do range checks on [] but not on release builds.  THis behavior varies from toolchain to toolchain. In some cases there are flags to enable it

Comment: The book seems to be from 1999 and can be viewed for free on the publisher's website. In any case it is therefore completely out-dated. You shouldn't learn C++ from any book that doesn't teach at least C++11 (from 2011). I am not sure whether the book is supposed to even teach standard C++ (C++98 from 1998 is the first standardization of the language), but if it is, then it has other errors, even on a quick look, e.g. it claims that implicit conversions from `double` to `int` is not allowed and that `(Point){ 3.0, 4.0 }` is an allowed cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you wrote:

```
char a = user_input[100];//this is undefined behavior
```

The expression `user_input[100]` leads to **undefined behavior** because you're going out of range of the `std::string`. If you want to make sure that you get an error while accessing out of range elements, then you can use [`std::string::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) member function like:

```
user_input.at(100)//this will perform bound checking and throw exception on invalid access
```

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Technically when you access a character outside the valid range of a string, you're getting undefined behavior.  The funny thing about undefined behavior is that it's completely undefined; you could get something reasonable, you could get total gibberish, your program could crash, or you could get demons flying from your nostrils.  All of those are valid responses to undefined behavior, and they need not be consistent from one run to the next.

Any reference you find that claims a particular result for undefined behavior is lying.